# Skype URI's not Working in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uri, ios9, skype, skype-uri.js

I had implemented a module for opening Skype app for various modules chat ,call, video call.It was working till iOS 8.

Below is link is followed for integration

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn745885.aspx

But it stopped working in iOS 9 now.

The below code is just opening the App-store searching Skype even when Skype is installed

```
BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];
    if(installed)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype:%@?chat",dataSource[indexPath.section]]]];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/skype-for-iphone/id304878510?mt=8"]];
    }
```

Any Alternative for this?Please guide.Thanks

Comment: Did you add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key in your Info.plist? You have to add skype url scheme to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in plist file

Comment: Thanks @gaRik i did that already it worked.

Comment: Can you show how looks properly working LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key for Skype?

Comment: i have answered it,check below

Comment: It looks the same in my app but still this line: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]] return false.

Comment: Did you do any additional changes other than the addition of LSApplicationQueriesSchemes?

Comment: i have added the code

Answer (score 7):

Below i am sharing the image  which worked for me.

I added the key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in Info.plist file for skype

[image]

```
BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];
    if(installed)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype:%@?chat",dataSource[indexPath.section]]]];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/skype-for-iphone/id304878510?mt=8"]];
    }
```