# open Skype in a Swift webview

Tags: swift, webview, skype

I want to open Skype in a Swift webview by just using a URL. Similar to something like the URL Scheme's provided by Apple for opening Apple Mail mailTo:// or telephone tel://.

1.) must i use the skype-API or just check if skype is installed with

```
@IBAction func skypeMe(sender: AnyObject) {
   let installed = UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "skype:")!)
   if installed {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "skype:echo123?call")!)
   } else {
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/skype/id304878510?mt=8")!)
   }
}
```

2.) how must i call this? (**skype:username?call**)

3.) my skype-login should be called automatically

4.) i want to choose the addressee

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254817/skype-uris-not-working-in-ios-9) link could help.

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL` launches skype automatically

Try `openURL(NSURL(string: "skype:")!)` It may launch skype,
where you could

choose the addresses. Or may not launch.

Comment: THX Iulian, that´s much more than i had til now